# Execute actions after render xml view in SAP UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, view, sapui5

I have two xml views, root and nested.

```
<mvc:View
        controllerName="test.controller.Root"
        xmlns="sap.m"
        xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <Page title="{i18n>appDescription}">
      <mvc:XMLView viewName="test.view.Nested"/>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Nested view has more elements, that have classes attrs.

I want execute this function, before render xml-view:

```
setActiveItem: function(){
    $('.myClassName').addClass('activeItem');
}
```

When I do this:

```
//....
return Controller.extend("test.controller.Nested", {
        onInit : function () {
            this.setActiveTopMenuItem();
        },


        setActiveTopMenuItem: function(){
            $('.myClassName').addClass('activeItem');
        },
//....
```

Nothing happens. I believe he is trying to add a class before it will be drawn view. Maybe I'm wrong. How to do it correctly?

Comment: In the `onInit` event handler, your view is not rendered yet, so basically you're adding a class to a non-existing DOM element. Better add the css manipulation in the `onAfterReendering` event handler